# Loading X509Certificate2 from pem file. Results in No credentials are available when used as a ClientCertificates

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

I need to make a request to a server.  This request requires a certificate in order to access the server.

If I load the P12 file and and register it as a certificate on my http Client.  It works fine.

```
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pathToTestCert, passToTestCert);
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate );
```

However if i use CreateFromPemFile to load the certificate from a pem file.

```
var clientCertificate= X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(purePem);
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
```

I get when sending the request to the server.

```
System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030E): No credentials are available in the security package
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(ISSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCH_CREDENTIALS* scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCH_CREDENTIALS* secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandleSchCredentials(X509Certificate2 certificate, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SslStreamCertificateContext certificateContext, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBuffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessBlob(Int32 frameSize)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReplyOnReAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Byte[] buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken
```

Note a pem file looks like this if opened in a text editor.

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
.
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
................
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.................
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: It looks like your .pem file contains two certificates. By default the first is used. Is that the correct one?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that question. we used openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.key.pem -nocerts -nodes to export the p12 to a pem file.

Comment: You can extract the certificates and put them in different files and use the public key when making your request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The TLS layer on Windows requires that the private key be written to disk (in a particular way).  The PEM-based certificate loading doesn't do that, only PFX-loading does.

The easiest way to make the TLS layer happy is to do

```
cert = new X509Certificate2(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));
```

That is, export the cert+key to a PFX, then import it again immediately (to get the side effect of the key being (temporarily) written to disk in a way that SChannel can find it).  You *shouldn't* need to bother with changing the PFX load flags off of the defaults, though some complicatedly constrained users might need to use MachineKeySet.

Comment: So is this just an issue on windows?  What happens when i run this in docker container?  btw it worked thanks.

Comment: And so that I don't forget how to do this. [How to use X509Certificate2 with pem file.](https://www.daimto.com/how-to-use-x509certificate2-with-pem-file/)