# How to avoid an error about "ephemeral keys" when using PEM files in .NET for web requests with MTLS?

Tags: c#, request, .net-8.0, mtls

I am trying to create a web request with .NET 8 on Windows using pem files as these are required by the API. This works when using python:

```py
import requests

url = "https://{SOMEURL}"

headers = {
    'SOMECOMPANY-Client-Id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cert=('example-cert.pem', 'example-key.pem'))

print(f'Response {response.text}')
print(f'Response status code {response.status_code}')
```

So I am happy that this works! However, when using .NET, I get an exception. Here is my C# code.

```cs
var url = "https://{SOMEURL}";
var clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
using var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
using var client = new HttpClient(handler);
// Load the certificate
var certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile("example-cert.pem", "example-key.pem");
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
// Add headers
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOMECOMPANY-Client-Id", clientId);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
// Make the GET request
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
// Read response content
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
// Print the response
Console.WriteLine($"Response: {responseContent}");
Console.WriteLine($"Response status code: {(int)response.StatusCode}");
```

This gives an exception (see below). So what should I do now? The web request I am trying to make is possible and succeeds! However, when using .NET, I do not succeed. Help me getting my C# code fixed. Probably, the underlying problem is related to this error message:

> Authentication failed because the platform does not support ephemeral
> keys.

Here is the exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the platform does not support ephemeral keys.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030E): Geen referenties beschikbaar in het beveiligingspakket
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(ISSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCH_CREDENTIALS* scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCH_CREDENTIALS* secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandleSchCredentials(SslAuthenticationOptions authOptions)
```

....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096812/loading-x509certificate2-from-pem-file-results-in-no-credentials-are-available might help

Comment: The previous comment should solve your problem. However, I recommend storing Client Certificates in the Windows Certificate Store. Windows and .NET are finicky when it comes to storing and accessing secrets. Lots of problems go away after you understand their security model.